# MongoDB critical section

Tags: mongodb

I need to perform a few operations (read and writes) on my mongodb without having another process interrupting. It's for an online game and when a user sends resources to another the following steps are performed:

1. Check his resource value
2. Abort if it's not enough
3. Insert a resource transaction
4. Decrement his resource value
5. Increment the other ones resource value

I'm concerned that while checking if its enough or inserting the resource transaction some other transaction has already been inserted and the values become invalid. How can I make sure that this part is executed in this order?

Comment: This is not really a good example of what you are asking for. You would do better to edit your question to contain your use case for your actions and some code pointing to how you are doing it. Otherwise this is juts asking for opinions at best and will as a result be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two ways:

- Use client side transactions to hold a "lock": http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/
- Or use versioning here whereby you hold a field with a `$inc`'d version number which gets updated every time you save and must be queried by whenever you go to save. A good example is within Vermongo: https://github.com/thiloplanz/v7files/wiki/Vermongo

Those seem to be the two most plausible ways I see of getting this done.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction is a almost forbidden word when talking about mongo. But you can perform steps 1,2 and 4 using a atomic uptade with `$inc` using resource value as condition, and then perform steps 3 and 5. You will not have support for rolling back on step if next steps fails.

Comment: Thanks! I guess as I want to be able to roll back i'll use the solution Sammaye posted.

Answer (score 1):

*I am an engineer at Tokutek*

TokuMX is a MongoDB replacement server that uses the same protocol and drivers and supports native multi-statement transactions on non-sharded setups.  What you want can be accomplished with a serializable transaction, which will take document-level locks on documents you touch.  This would be done something like

```
> db.beginTransaction("serializable");
> if (resourcesInsufficient()) { db.rollbackTransaction(); }
> // insert and update
> db.commitTransaction()
```

Again, this is not supported in sharding but may be useful for your application.  More details, features and limitations are discussed [here](http://www.tokutek.com/2013/10/introducing-tokumx-transactions-for-mongodb-applications/).

Comment: thanks! but i have already rewritten the parts of my code according to the previous answers :/